# Методы с "unresolved reference" (перевод с java на kotlin)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

При переводе приложения с Java на Kotlin некоторые джавишные методы Android Studio подчёркивает красным и объясняет это как "Unresolved reference":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я могу заменить эту строку

```
val str = hexStr.substring(i, i + 2)
```

на эквивалентную, которую Android Studio не подчёркивает:

```
val str = hexStr.subSequence(i, i + 2).toString()
```

Это работает, и приводит к аналогичному результату.

Но что вызывало мой вопрос: при том, что данные методы подчёркнуты красным, приложение всё равно компилируется, запускается и работает. И собственно вопрос: насколько "страшно" оставлять эти методы "красными", к каким "побочным эффектам" это может привести? Например, их использование сродни deprecated методам - сейчас всё работает, а в будущем может привести к поломке? Или же это влияет просто на "красоту" кода?

Comment: У вас что-то не так с гредлом/самой студией. Попробуйте удалить все несвязанные с логикой части (`.gradle`, `.idea`, `*.iml` и прочее что обычно добавляют в .gitignore) и пересоздать проект. Или для начала clean/rebuild/invalidate caches.

Comment: Ну и прочие дефолтные советы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712046/kotlin-unresolved-reference-in-intellij

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, спасибо большое, Ваши комментарии навели меня на путь решения этой проблемы! Оказалось, что нужно всего лишь вместо kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 использовать kotlin-stdlib-jdk8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После замены строки в *build.gradle*

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

на

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```

и синхронизации gradle Android Studio перестала подчёркивать красным данные методы.

Comment: Я бы не советовал `-jdk*` использовать, лучше просто `kotlin-stdlib`.